# Alt Flux не работает декоратор @bind

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babel, flux

Пыталась разобраться с архитектурой alt и flux

Не могу понять, почему сборщик ругается на декоратор @bind

[image: Вот что выдает браузер]

вот исходный код файла, где возникает ошибка:

```
import alt from '../alt'
import Actions from '../actions'
import {decorate, bind, datasourse} from 'alt-utils/lib/decorators'

@decorate(alt)
class ChatStore {
  constructor() {
    this.state = {user: null}
  }

  @bind(Actions.login)
  login(user) {
    this.setState({user: user})
    console.log('ChatStore user', user);
  }
}

export default alt.createStore(ChatStore)
```

Вот полная версия исходного кода: https://bitbucket.org/AtNovember/studyflux/

Comment: Как ругается-то хоть? Я к слову не вижу у вас в package.json трансформа для декораторов, бабель (шестой) их из коробки кажется не умеет

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму Спасибо! Да, забыла скриншот прикрепить. Вот так ругается https://i.stack.imgur.com/eShPy.png

Comment: У вас нет трансформа для декораторов. Как минимум. Текущий бабель декораторы из коробки не умеет, причина сейчас именно в этом. Магические строчки я за вас не напишу сейчас, разбираться времени нет, но причина собственно именно в этом. Если хотите сама разобраться, курить сюда: https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-decorators/

Comment: Плюс вероятно надо будет потанцевать с бубном чтобы плагин декораторов отрабатывал раньше всяких других пресетов, но это потом уже

Comment: О: http://technologyadvice.github.io/es7-decorators-babel6/

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s3nfIzWI05I - нашла классный туториал по настройке биндингов